# Applications keeps closing vs 2012

Tags: c++, windows

My application keeps closing when debugging. I'm not able to view what the "results" are since it goes too fast.

I've been looking at many different forums and topics and all the solutions given just wont apply. I've tried different commands before returns 0; etc and also changing an option in the project.

I'm just starting and trying to learn from the c++ primer but this is frustrating me already :).

Following is my code, please help!

```
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
    int sum = 0, val = 1;
    while (val <= 10) {
        sum +=val;
        ++ val;
    }
    std::cout << "Sum of 1 to 10  inclusive is "
              << sum << std::endl;
    Console.Read();
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Have you set any breakpoints? Try building in Release mode -- the console won't close immediately.

Comment: Console.Read is available ONLY on C++ .NET projects. The C++ way to read from the console is `std::cin.get();`

Comment: Guessing you are using visual studio - pressing ctrl+F5 will run it and pause for you. You won't be able to "debug" but you will be able to see the output.

Comment: Just hit F10 to start debugging...

Comment: try `system("pause");` or `getch();`

Comment: Learning how to use the debugger is an important skill to acquire.   Try setting a breakpoint on the last statement.  Note how you can now look at the console window.  Nevertheless, this is of course also going to happen when you run your program from a shortcut on the desktop.  The "Hit any key to continue" approach is boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
    int sum = 0, val = 1;
    while (val <= 10) {
        sum +=val;
        ++ val;
    }
    std::cout << "Sum of 1 to 10  inclusive is "
              << sum << std::endl;

    std::cin.get(); // hackish but better than system("PAUSE");
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick reply. That was one of the solutions that isn't working nor disturbing the app. Using your code doesn't work either.

Comment: No such thing as Console.Read EXCEPT on C++.NET projects

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ... Oh... Ew... I feel dirty just thinking about it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do `Console.Read();`, do `std::cin.get();`.

Comment: Error 1 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'return' c:\users\furjin\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\project1\project1\source.cpp 13 1 Project1

Comment: Yes, there was a missing semi-colon :v

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using Visual Studio:

`Debug` builds will run until they hit a breakpoint or until the program finishes (which ever comes first). If the program finishes, the console closes. Place a break point on the line containing `return 0;` and your console will stay open until you click Continue.

`Release` builds will run until the program finishes. If the program finishes, you will be prompted to `Press any key to continue. . .` *and* the console will stay open.

If you are not setting breakpoints in such a small program, you are wasting your resources -- debug mode will impact the performance of the program.

Thus, you should build in `Release` mode and forget about using `std::cin.get()`.